# Не работает тег <a>

Tags: html, css

Кнопка `<a class="btn btn--red" href="#">Find Out More</a>` не реагирует на наведение и нажатие. Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6c7279;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}


/*Container
*------*/

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*Header
*------*/

.header {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
}

.header__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 35px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #515369;
  align-items: center;
}


/*Nav
------*/

.nav {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav__link {
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: opacity 0.2 linear;
}

.nav:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


/*Intro
------*/

.intro {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 90px;
  height: 750px;
  background: #31344e url("img/intro-bg.jpg") center no-repeat;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.intro__title {
  font-size: 65px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.intro__inner {
  max-width: 970px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.intro__subtitle {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}


/*Button
------*/

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 14px 40px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 0;
}

.btn--red {
  background-color: #e84545;
}

.btn--red:hover {
  background-color: #d33838;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Active Box</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo:400i|Montserrat|Montserrat+Alternates:400,600&display=swap&subset=cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<!-- HEADER -->

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header__inner">
        <div class="header__logo">
          <img src="img/activebox-logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <nav class="nav">
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Works</a>
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">About</a>
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Testimonials</a>
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Download</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- INTRO -->
  <div class="intro">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="intro__inner">
        <h1 class="intro__title">Welcome to my Page</h1>
        <h2 class="intro__subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam nam in sequi, unde quia cumque tempore iste nulla nemo doloribus et officia magni, quibusdam laudantium hic placeat aliquam, totam. Voluptates.</h2>
        <a class="btn btn--red" href="#">Find Out More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А как он должен работать?

Comment: Как ссылка, но при наведении курсора мыши на ссылку, курсор же меняется и как-то реагирует. У меня такого в этом месте не работает

Comment: так у вас же там прописан адрес ссылки "#"

Comment: Выше ссылки реагируют, самый последний нет, если даже добавить тег button.

Comment: Честно, не могу понять в чем суть вашей проблемы

Comment: у меня при наведении цвет меняется на красный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, зачем Вы шапку до пяток натянули, но `.header {height: 100%;}` при `position: absolute; z-index: 1000;` - это не совсем правильно, т.к. перекрывает всю страницу. Закатал шапку:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6c7279;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: border-box; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin: 0; }

p { margin: 0 0 10px; }


/*Container
*------*/

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*Header
*------*/

.header {
  /* Вот тут были носки с капюшоном */
  /* height: 100%; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
}

.header__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 35px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #515369;
  align-items: center;
}


/*Nav
------*/

.nav {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav__link {
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: opacity 0.2 linear;
}

.nav:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

.nav__link:hover { opacity: 1; }


/*Intro
------*/

.intro {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 90px;
  height: 750px;
  background: #31344e url("img/intro-bg.jpg") center no-repeat;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.intro__title {
  font-size: 65px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.intro__inner {
  max-width: 970px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.intro__subtitle {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}


/*Button
------*/

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 14px 40px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 0;
}

.btn--red { background-color: #e84545; }

.btn--red:hover { background-color: #d33838; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Active Box</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo:400i|Montserrat|Montserrat+Alternates:400,600&display=swap&subset=cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<!-- HEADER -->

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header__inner">
        <div class="header__logo">
          <img src="img/activebox-logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <nav class="nav">
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Works</a>
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">About</a>
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Testimonials</a>
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Download</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- INTRO -->
  <div class="intro">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="intro__inner">
        <h1 class="intro__title">Welcome to my Page</h1>
        <h2 class="intro__subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam nam in sequi, unde quia cumque tempore iste nulla nemo doloribus et officia magni, quibusdam laudantium hic placeat aliquam, totam. Voluptates.</h2>
        <a class="btn btn--red" href="#">Find Out More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Улыбнуло :))  /* Вот тут были носки с капюшоном */

Comment: Спасибо, большое)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn--red:hover {
  background-color: #d33838;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```